# Send another <input> value in Ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

here is my upload function

```
function ajaxFileUpload() {

    $("#loading")
        .ajaxStart(function () {
        $(this).html('loading...');
        $('#buttonUpload').hide();
    })
        .ajaxComplete(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#buttonUpload').show();
    });

    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: '_card_upload.php',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });

    return false;

}
```

above function allow user to upload one file to my server, but I need user to specific that this image is public image or not? by add some checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="public_card" name="public_card" align="absmiddle" />
```

in upload form

the problem is i dont know how to send **a value in checkbox** to `url:'_card_upload.php'`
at the same time.

how do i send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `data` parameter to the `ajaxFileUpload` call:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: '_card_upload.php',
    data: {
        public_card: $('#public_card')[0].checked ? 'yes' : 'no'
    },
    secureuri: false,
    fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: how PHP recieve public_card value? is it **$_POST['public_card'];**

Comment: @Giffary Yes, it should be there.